# Homological Algebra issues in showing a moduli functor is representable

Tags: algebraic-geometry, homological-algebra, moduli-space

Let $h$ be the moduli functor $(\text{Schemes}_{\mathbb{C}})^{op}\to \text{Sets}$ described as follows.

On objects $h(X)$ gives us the following: a line bundle $L\to X$ with an injective map of vector bundles $i:L \to X\times \mathbb{C}^{n+1}$ with a quotient that is a vector bundle (i.e. a constant rank vector bundle map).

On morphisms, we apply the pullback the line bundle and its vector bundle map.

Now, we want to show that this moduli functor $h$ is representable and is naturally isomorphic to $h^{\mathbb{P}^n}$ .

$h(X)$ gives us a short exact sequence of locally free sheaves, $0\to \mathcal{L}\to \mathcal{O}_X^{n+1}\to \mathcal{Q}\to 0$ where $\mathcal{L}$ is the sheaf associated to the line bundle $L$ and $Q$ is the quotient bundle with a locally free sheaf $\mathcal{Q}$ associated to it.

This is where I start to lose track of what's going on.

"Taking the dual, this is equivalent to an exact sequence,

$0\to \mathcal{Q}^{\vee}\to \mathcal{O}_X^{n+1}\to \mathcal{L}^{\vee}\to 0$

of locally free sheaves. Since the kernel of a map of locally free sheaves is automatically
locally free, this is equivalent to just specifying the surjection $\iota^{\vee}: \mathcal{O}_X^{n+1}\to \mathcal{L}^{\vee}$. Such a
surjection is determined by specifying sections $s_0,...,s_n\in H^0(X,\mathcal{L}^{\vee}) $ without a common zero...."

Question 1: Why is taking duals exact? In particular, why is it right exact?

Question 2: The idea is that we want to find $n+1$ linearly independent basepoint-free sections of $\mathcal{L^{\vee}}$ (or perhaps it should be $\mathcal{L}$?) to construct a map $X\to \mathbb{P}^n$ (that's what $h^{\mathbb{P}^n}(X)$ is). But taking global sections is only left-exact so $H^0(X,\mathcal{O}_X^n)\to H^0(X,\mathcal{L}^{\vee})$ need not be a surjection of vector spaces (and even if it were we'd still need that $H^0(X,\mathcal{Q}^{\vee})$ to be exactly $0$). How are we concluding that $H^0(X,\mathcal{L}^{\vee})$ has dimension $\geq n+1$?

Comment: Your description of h(X) is weird: you say that it is a line bundle and a map and stuff, but it should be a set.

Comment: Locally free sheaves are locally free, and you can check the exactness of the dual of a short exact sequence locally.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez I guess what I am saying is it is a set and the data in that $h(X)$ is the line bundle with extra stuff.

Comment: What you mean is that h(X) is the set of all line bundles endowed with a something.

Comment: It is not because the original sequence is exact locally that the dual is exact: it is because locally it is split.